# Back up data from Azure cosmos DB to blob storage

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I need to back up the data in the Azure Cosmos database to Azure blob storage (managed by storage account). I did that by copy functions in Data factory and scheduled the daily back up trigger. Currently the back up is only in the form of overwrite.

**Question**: how can I configure the storage account and back up pipeline in the Data Factory that the storage can back up the data in the staging form so that I can download different version of the data I backed up?

Comment: You should be able to create each backup with a unique file name using a timestamp to avoid overwriting the previous. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I think there is no ready-made thing in ADF to achieve, you can check the snapshot by integrating the azure function, and operate the blob content inside the azure function. Or you can directly use azure function for regular inspection.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I configure the storage account and back up pipeline in the
> Data Factory that the storage can back up the data in the staging form
> so that I can download different version of the data I backed up?

There is no ready-made thing to realize your idea in ADF. You can check the snapshot by integrating the azure function, and operate the blob content inside the azure function.

Or you can directly use azure function for regular inspection:

```
import logging
import os

import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, ClientSecretCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.storage.queue import QueueService, QueueMessageFormat
import requests
import time

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    # DefaultAzureCredential supports managed identity or environment configuration (see docs)
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

    # parse parameters
    storage_account_source = os.environ["par_storage_account_name_source"]
    storage_account_source_url = "https://" + storage_account_source + ".blob.core.windows.net"
    storage_account_backup = os.environ["par_storage_account_name_backup"]
    storage_account_backup_url = "https://" + storage_account_backup + ".blob.core.windows.net"

    # create blob client for backup and source
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    client_source = BlobServiceClient(account_url=storage_account_source_url, credential=credential)
    client_backup = BlobServiceClient(account_url=storage_account_backup_url, credential=credential)

    # Create queue clients
    queue_service = QueueService(account_name=os.environ['par_storage_account_name_queue'], account_key=os.environ['par_storage_account_key_queue'])
    queue_service.encode_function = QueueMessageFormat.text_base64encode

    # Get all blobs in sourcecontainer
    container_source_list = client_source.list_containers()
    for container in container_source_list:
        # Log container name
        logging.info(container.name)
        container_source = client_source.get_container_client(container.name)
        
        # Get all blobs in container
        prev_blob_name = ""
        prev_blob_etag = ""        
        blob_source_list = container_source.list_blobs(include=['snapshots'])
        for blob in blob_source_list:

            if blob.snapshot == None:
                # Blob that is not snapshot.
                # 1. Check if snapshot needs to be created
                if prev_blob_name != blob.name:
                    # New blob without snapshot, create snapshot/backup
                    logging.info("new blob" + blob.name + ", create snapshot/backup")
                    create_snapshot(client_source, queue_service, container.name, blob.name, blob.etag)
                elif prev_blob_etag != blob.etag:
                    # Existing blob that has changed, create snapshot/backup
                    logging.info(blob.name + "has changed, create snapshot/backup")
                    create_snapshot(client_source, queue_service, container.name, blob.name, blob.etag)
    
                # 2. Check if incremental backup needs to be created
                # get blob backup and source properties
                blob_source = client_source.get_blob_client(container=container.name, blob=blob.name)
                source_last_modified = blob_source.get_blob_properties()['last_modified']
                source_etag = str(blob_source.get_blob_properties()['etag']).replace("\"","")
                blob_name_backup = append_timestamp_etag(blob.name, source_last_modified, source_etag)
                blob_backup = client_backup.get_blob_client(container=container.name + "bak", blob=blob_name_backup)
                blob_exists = check_blob_exists(blob_backup)
                # Check if blob exists
                if blob_exists == False:
                    # Latest blob does not yet exist in backup, create message on queue to update
                    queue_json = "{" + "\"container\":\"{}\", \"blob_name\":\"{}\", \"etag\":\"{}\"".format(container.name, blob.name, source_etag) + "}"
                    logging.info("backup needed for: " + queue_json)
                    queue_service.put_message(os.environ['par_queue_name'], queue_json)                
                    #asyncio.run(copy_adf_blob_source_backup(blob_source, blob_backup))
            
            prev_blob_name = blob.name
            prev_blob_etag = blob.etag

    result = {"status": "ok"}
    return func.HttpResponse(str(result))

def check_blob_exists(bc_blob):
    # Check if blob already exists
    # todo: see if this can be done without try except
    try:
        bc_blob.get_blob_properties()
        return True
    except:
        return False

def create_snapshot(client_source, queue_service, container_name, blob_name, blob_etag):
    # create snapshot
    blob_client = client_source.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)
    blob_client.create_snapshot()

def append_timestamp_etag(filename, source_modified, etag):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return "{name}_{modified}_{etag}{ext}".format(name=name, modified=source_modified, etag=etag, ext=ext)
```

Above is based on Httptrigger, you can change it to Timertrigger, below is the doc of Timertrigger of azure function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python